# Installing package halo gives error: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

Im trying to install Halo by using,

```
pip install halo
```

I get the following error message:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/9s/vjh90rsn4xl5587hr11qpjjh0000gn/T/pip-install-L5LD_D/halo/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/9s/vjh90rsn4xl5587hr11qpjjh0000gn/T/pip-install-L5LD_D/halo/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/9s/vjh90rsn4xl5587hr11qpjjh0000gn/T/pip-install-L5LD_D/halo/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/9s/vjh90rsn4xl5587hr11qpjjh0000gn/T/pip-install-L5LD_D/halo/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error in halo setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected ',' or end-of-list in backports.shutil_get_terminal_size>=1.0.0;python_version < '3.3' at ;python_version < '3.3'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

My python version is 2.7.10.

I made some research and tried the following solutions,

```
brew install halo
```

This did not work and my terminal returned:

```
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I checked my Formulae in Homebrew and could not find Halo. However, I found other packages so my Homebrew work otherwise.

I tried chaning my python version to 3 by changing alias and installing halo again, and it did not work either.

```
alias python='python3'
```

Error massage was the same as for python2, as above.

I need halo for a school lab, and im using Mac.

Comment: Please fix your formatting. This is not Javascript

Comment: Fixed! Could you help solve this problem now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a known bug for that package:

https://github.com/manrajgrover/halo/issues/79

You just have to update setup tools via: pip install -U setuptools

If that doesn't work, try adding the --user flag: pip install --user -U setuptools

Comment: It did not work either using "pip install - U setuptools. I get error message, "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: ..."

Comment: I tried

pip install --user -U setuptools

and it worked! I had to add --user.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to reflect the changes you made

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
pip3 install --user package-name  # for Python3
pip install -U setuptools && pip install halo  # for Python3

pip install --user package-name   # for Python2
pip3 install -U setuptools && pip install halo # for Python2
```

Comment: This did not work either. I get the same error message as the other suggested solution, "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: ..."

Comment: check the answer and tell me the result.