# Add python setuptools dependency from specific github commit (instead of PyPI package)

Tags: python, git, pip, setuptools

I have tried the following installation methods with no success to install a python package with a specific commit of a git repository:

`$ python3 setup.py install --user`

`$ pip3 install -e .`

`$ python3 -m pip install -e .`

Here is `setup.py`:

```
import sys
from setuptools import setup

install_requires = [
    # 'numpy>=1.9.0' # works
    # 'numpy' # works
    # 'git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy' # works
    # 'git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy@4c83c0444c68b89b051f7ef8d8eb1a2276439d78' # does not work
    # 'git+git://github.com/numpy/numpy.git@4c83c0444c68b89b051f7ef8d8eb1a2276439d78' # does not work
    # 'numpy@git+git://github.com/numpy/numpy.git@4c83c04' # installs the "best match" for numpy, not this commit
    # 'numpy @ git+ssh://git@github.com/numpy/numpy@4c83c0444c68b89b051f7ef8d8eb1a2276439d78#egg=numpy' # installs the "best match" for numpy, not this commit
    ]

setup(
      install_requires=install_requires,
      )
```

I've updated pip and setuptools both locally and as root:
`pip install -U pip setuptools`

No change.

I've scanned setuptools, pip and other docs with no example that provides a working result.

How you specify a specific commit of a specific git repo as a dependency in a python package using setuptools?

Comment: no, those answers seem to have a way to identify the package by release version but not by specific commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpip%5D+commit

Comment: `install_requires = ['git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy@8b15e57718042c75af22a25a7d604fa0f938f16e']`

Comment: `'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'+https:/'"` @phd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59164147/7976758: `pip install -U pip setuptools` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install_requires+must+be+a+string+or+list+of+strings

Comment: Yes, `pip` is the only way to install from git repo.

Comment: does `python3 setup.py install` implicitly use pip, then? It works fine for `git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy` but not for `git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy@4c83c0444c68b89b051f7ef8d8eb1a2276439d78`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224070/discussion-between-khaverim-and-phd).

Answer (score -1):

You can find the correct way of doing it here:
https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#packages-not-on-pypi

The  important thing is not to give a link to a git repository, but a link to a tarball which is generated by Github

EG

dependency_links=['http://github.com/user/repo/tarball/master#egg=package-1.0']

Comment: how do you specify the commit? This just downloads the master branch, i guess